How do I get my iframe to stay active when the app is minimized?
I am writing a CefSharp.WinForms program that can control my website automatically. It will work fine if my Application is still visible on the screen, but if the application is minimized it will not work anymore specifically the iframe will stop playing.
Is there any way I can minimize the application and still play the iframe with winforms C#? Because I need to run it on the server and when I exit the remote it will stop working
This is the code in my form1:
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WinFormsAppElearning
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private bool isLoginAttempted = false;
        private string userId = "defaultUserId";
        private bool isRunningInBackground = false;
        public Form1(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);
        }
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized && !isRunningInBackground)
            {
                browser.Focus();                 
                isRunningInBackground = true;

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                    {
                        CheckProgressBar();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }

                    isRunningInBackground = false;
                });
            }
        }

        private void InitializeChromium()
        {
            if (!(Cef.IsInitialized ?? false))             
            {
                var settings = new CefSettings
                {
                    WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true,
                    PersistSessionCookies = true
                };

                settings.PersistSessionCookies = true;
                userId = txtUsername.Text;
                string cachePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Elearning", "Cache_" + userId);
                settings.RootCachePath = cachePath;

                // Uncomment for remote debugging
                // settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;

                Cef.Initialize(settings);
            }
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://example.com/login")
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnBrowserInitialized;

            browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
        }

        private void OnBrowserInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                // Uncomment to show DevTools
                // browser.ShowDevTools();

                // browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("console.log('Browser Initialized');");
            }
        }

        private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsLoading)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    if (browser.Address.Contains("scorm/player.php"))
                    {
                        txtUsername.Visible = false;
                        txtPassword.Visible = false;
                        btnLogin.Visible = false;
                        CheckProgressBar();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CheckForLogin();
                    }
                }));
            }
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = txtUsername.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check username and password");
                return; 
            }

            InitializeChromium();
            browser.Load("http://example.com/login");
        }

        private void CheckForLogin()
        {
            if (!isLoginAttempted)
            {
                string username = txtUsername.Text;
                string password = txtPassword.Text;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                {
                    return; 
                }
                // Inject script to fill username and password, then submit the form
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('username').value = '{username}';");
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('password').value = '{password}';");
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('button[type=\"submit\"]').click();");
                isLoginAttempted = true;
            }
            else if (!browser.Address.Contains("/login"))
            {
                browser.Load("http://example.com/mod/scorm/player.php?a=21&currentorg=RSLBYTyDkzj5W_organization&scoid=67");
                isLoginAttempted = false;
            }
        }

        private void OnJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string currentUrl = e.Message.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(currentUrl);

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Text += currentUrl;
            }));
        }

        private bool isPlayButtonClicked = false;

        private async void CheckProgressBar()
        {
            string currentUrl = browser.Address;
            if (currentUrl == "http://example.com/mod/scorm/player.php?a=21&currentorg=RSLBYTyDkzj5W_organization&scoid=67")
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        btnLab.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    btnLab.Visible = true;
                }
                btnLab.Text = "Text";
            }
            else if (currentUrl == "http://example.com/mod/scorm/player.php?a=22&currentorg=WlfhdtXvGehiY_organization&scoid=70")
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        btnLab.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    btnLab.Visible = true;
                }
                btnLab.Text = "Text";
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        btnLab.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    btnLab.Visible = true;
                }
                btnLab.Text = "TEXT";
            }

            string script2 = @"
function checkProgressBar() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        let attempt = 0; 
        const maxAttempts = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
        let checkInterval = 1000; 

        function check() {
            const iframe = document.getElementById('scorm_object');
            if (!iframe) {
                attempt++;
                if (attempt >= maxAttempts) {
                    resolve('Unable to find iframe after multiple attempts.');
                    return;
                }
                setTimeout(check, checkInterval); 
                return;
            }

            const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; 
            const progressLabel = innerDoc.querySelector('.progressbar__label'); 
            const timeLabel = innerDoc.querySelector('.progressbar__label_type_time'); 
            const preloader = innerDoc.querySelector('.preloader'); 

            if (preloader && preloader.style.display !== 'none') {
                resolve('Session has expired!');
                return;
            }
            
            let totalProgresscheck = 10; 

            if (progressLabel) {
                const progressValue = progressLabel.getAttribute('aria-label');
                if (progressValue) {
                    const [completedProgress, totalProgress] = progressValue.trim().split(' / '); 

                    if (timeLabel) {
                        const timeValue = timeLabel.getAttribute('aria-label');
                        if (timeValue) {
                            const [completedTime, totalTime] = timeValue.trim().split(' / '); 

                            totalProgresscheck = totalTime; 
                            console.log(completedProgress,totalProgress,completedTime,totalTime);
                            if (completedProgress !== totalProgress && completedTime === totalTime) {
                                setTimeout(1000);
                                const nextButton = innerDoc.querySelector('.universal-control-panel__button_next'); 
                                const playButton = innerDoc.querySelector('.universal-control-panel__button_play-pause');

                                console.log(playButton);
                                if (nextButton) {
                                      if(playButton.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'false')
                                        {
                                            nextButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
                                            nextButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
                                        }
                                }
                                setTimeout(3000);
                            } else if (completedProgress == totalProgress && completedTime === totalTime) {
                                  setTimeout(3000);
                                 resolve('Next');
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (totalProgresscheck) {
                let totalSeconds;
                if (!isNaN(totalProgresscheck)) {
                    totalSeconds = parseInt(totalProgresscheck, 10);
                } else {
                    const [minutes, seconds] = totalProgresscheck.split(':').map(Number);
                    totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + seconds;
                }

                checkInterval = totalSeconds / 10; 
                console.log(""Check interval (seconds):"", checkInterval);
            } else {
                console.warn(""Invalid totalProgress value:"", totalProgress);
            }

            attempt++; 
            if (attempt >= maxAttempts) {
                resolve('Session has expired!');
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(check, checkInterval * 1000); 
        }
        check(); 
    });
}

checkProgressBar();

";

            if (browser != null && !browser.IsDisposed && browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                var resultProgress = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script2);
                if (resultProgress.Success)
                {
                    if (resultProgress.Result != null)
                    {
                        string resultMessage = resultProgress.Result.ToString();
                        if (resultMessage.Contains("Session has expired!"))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(this, resultMessage, "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            Application.Restart();
                        }
                        else if (resultMessage.Contains("Next"))
                        {
                            nextSlide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void nextSlide()
        {
            if (browser != null && !browser.IsDisposed && browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.universal-control-panel__button_next').click();");
            }
        }
    }
}

and i also tried to use:
WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true;
but not effective
Someone please help me

This looks like quite a lot of code. It would help us help you if you reduced it to a [mre].

I just want to find a solution to make the iframe run when minimizing the application. I can't find a solution for it. I simply have an iframe and I will play it on the web with chromium web but the problem is if I minimize the website or the application falls off it will not continue to play the iframe. What I am looking for is a way to make the iframe still run even if I minimize it or move to a new tag

when you say "playing" I assume there's a video there?  It's somewhat common for sites to use visibility api for pausing video when visibility state changed.  (So check your web site code... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event )

you should probably remove "selenium-webdriver" tag here.  I don't see any Selenium code, just injected scripts.  (you should be able to register better hooks there...)
